# rxjs: cancelling a debounced observable

Tags: rxjs

I have an observable `Subject` that emits some changes with debouncing:

```js
someSubject.pipe(
  debounceTime(5000),
).subscribe(response => {
  console.log('Value is', response);
})
```

Now, I need a `Stop` button somewhere on the screen that would cancel my debounced emit. So I create a button:

```js
const stopObs = new Subject();
...
<button onClick={() => stopObs.next()}>Stop</button>
```

and modify my subscription like so:

```js
someSubject.pipe(
  debounceTime(5000),
  takeUntil(stopObs),
).subscribe(response => {
  console.log('Value is', response);
})
```

This works fine, after hitting "Stop" I stop getting values in console, but there is a problem: the observable is stopped forever. And I need it to be able to emit new values, I only need to cancel already started debounced emits.

My first thought was to create a new subject and use `repeatWhen`:

```js
const startObs = new Subject();
...
<button onClick={() => startObs.next()}>Start</button>

...
someSubject.pipe(
  debounceTime(5000),
  takeUntil(stopObs),
  repeatWhen(() => startObs)
).subscribe(response => {
  console.log('Value is', response);
})
```

But there's another problem: if I hit "Start" button more than one time and emit more than one value to `startObs`, then I start getting multiple `console.log`'s for single debounced value!

So is there a way to cancel only debounced emits without stopping the entire observable?

Comment: It looks like you could just use `repeat()` instead of `repeatWhen()` since you're using just Subject so it sohouldn't matter that you'll stay subscribed to the source Observable.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`debounceTime`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/debounceTime.ts) is just

```js
const duration = timer(dueTime, scheduler);
return debounce(() => duration);
```

I think you can solve the problem like this:

```js
someSubject.pipe(
  debounce(() => timer(5000).pipe(takeUntil(stopObs))),
)
```

If you want to send the last value when the timer is cancelled due to `stopObs`, you could try this:

```js
someSubject.pipe(
  debounce(
    () => timer(5000)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(stopObs),
        isEmpty(),
      )
  ),
)
```

[`isEmpty()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/isEmpty.ts#L68) will emit `true` immediately before a `complete` notification, which is what `debounce` needs in order to send the last received value. If the timer completes without `stopObs`'s involvement, `isEmpty` will emit `false` instead of `true`, but this still works well for `debounce`, since it only needs a value from the inner observable.